MAGENTO 2 - Add Filter to Specific SKU in Order Grid
I need to add a select box (include or exclude) to filter a specific product sku (TEST).
If is selected "include" option should be show the order that has this specific sku (TEST).
If is selected "exclude" option should be show the order that hasn't this specific sku (TEST).
Thanks for advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
